# Redirect archive.ubuntu.com to a mirror on DNS level

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I rely a lot Docker images, and is impractical to change the /etc/apt/source.list for each of them, so I want to redirect `archive.ubuntu.com` to a mirror on DNS level (I have my own dnsmasq/unbound on the network already).

My setup is a Pi-Hole running on port 53 (pihole-FTL 4.0, with dnsmasq underlying) which points to an unbound running on port 5353:

```
server=127.0.0.1#5353
```

To achieve the redirect, I added those lines to the unbound configuration:

```
local-zone: "archive.ubuntu.com." typetransparent
local-data: "archive.ubuntu.com. CNAME ubuntu.mirror.su.se."
```

And it seems to work fine (unbound on port 5353):

```
root@raspberrypi:~# dig +short -p 5353 @127.0.0.1 archive.ubuntu.com
ubuntu.mirror.su.se.
root@raspberrypi:~# dig +short -p 5353 @127.0.0.1 ubuntu.mirror.su.se
193.11.30.223
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

The weird part is that dnsmasq loses itself with this:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# dig +short -p 53 @127.0.0.1 archive.ubuntu.com
ubuntu.mirror.su.se.
root@raspberrypi:~# dig +short -p 53 @127.0.0.1 ubuntu.mirror.su.se
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

For me, it does not make much sense as dnsmasq should just relay whatever unbound sent as answer, but somehow dnsmasq is doing something with this.

First I thought it could be DNSSEC validation, but then the error should have been in the archive.ubuntu.com, not the mirror.

Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Can't you just change your hosts file? If it's downloading over https you might have issues.

Comment: No, because that forces me to maintain the IP addresses up to date, which I am trying to avoid. Also, this is DNS level, nothing related to https yet (and archive.ubuntu.com answers in http).

Comment: You haven't outlined what you're trying to achieve clearly. Please edit your question to tell us your big picture goal. Are you trying to create your own docker image archive?

Comment: @Tim I don't want to touch my Docker images at all, but still benefit from a mirror.

Comment: In another way: when I query X, I want it to return me the IP addresses defined on Y.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like unbound itself can do it:

```
local-zone: "archive.ubuntu.com" redirect
local-data: "archive.ubuntu.com. CNAME se.archive.ubuntu.com."
```

This yields:

```
$ docker run --rm -it test bash
root@3f1c7eff6ebc:/# dig archive.ubuntu.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.5-Ubuntu <<>> archive.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14903
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;archive.ubuntu.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
archive.ubuntu.com. 3265    IN  CNAME   se.archive.ubuntu.com.
se.archive.ubuntu.com.  3265    IN  CNAME   ftp.acc.umu.se.
ftp.acc.umu.se.     3265    IN  A   194.71.11.165
ftp.acc.umu.se.     3265    IN  A   194.71.11.173

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.2#53(192.168.1.2)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 28 19:31:27 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 142
```